# A function that gets called outside the flow of control?

Tags: javascript, function

So, I've been trying to understand a specific js library by running it through my browser's debugger, and something happens that just confuses me.

I first encountered this in the Phaser game library, but I've seen it another library as well. I'll use Phaser as an example:

```
<script>
(function(){
    var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.CANVAS, '');
    game.state.add('Game', Game);
    game.state.start('Game');
})();
</script>
```

So that anonymous function finishes setting some things up, and I step over and out of that function, and after a couple more steps (the pointer just sitting at the top of the html doc in the meantime) my program out of nowhere ends up here:

```
Phaser.Device._readyCheck = function () {

var readyCheck = this._readyCheck;

....

}
```

It didn't look like anything within my flow of control called that function, so how did I get here? What's calling this function? I've read a bit about 'asynchronous functions' and that sounds like a pretty good explanation, but the stuff I've glanced at on Google don't really explain anything well, so I can't say I understand it enough to be sure. I'm relatively new to JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library sets up event handlers for various events which then get called asynchronously. In this case, event handlers are setup to to watch for the completion of the loading of the DOM, among other things, so that the internal state of the library can be initialized. You can see how it happens in the source

`src/system/Device.js:Phaser.Device._readyCheck`

and `Phaser.Device.whenReady` in the same file. With a little searching you can easily find who calls whenReady.

Comment: Hey, thanks so much! You were right: they set that DOM event handler in the Phaser.Game constructor which calls up that _readyCheck function.

Comment: No problem, glad it was useful. As you've noticed, you'll find this sort of thing in most js frameworks - initialization sets up a bunch of event handlers and the bulk of the logic is driven by responses to events. This can make the magic a little cumbersome to unravel, even with a debugger. Run unminified and keep the source handy for perusal. Looking at how the initial scaffolding is set up will give you a decent idea of where you might want to put a breakpoint and dig around bits of the implementation that you want to understand better.

Answer (score 0):

The function you pointed out at the top is a self-executing function. `();` causes everything contained in the preceding parentheses to be executed immediately.

Comment: Also known as an Immediately Invoked Function Expression (`IIFE` - pronounced "iffy"). Helps when googling

Comment: That's not the function I was talking about. I know that the anonymous function is self-calling, but that isn't so with the _readyCheck function.